# Multi File Connection Manager in SSIS

Tags: ssis

i am working on a scenerio where i need to load 3 csv files into my table. For this purpose am using 3 flat file connection managers.

Now instead of using 3 flat file connection managers i need to use only one connection Manager for all the 3 files.

I came to know we can use Multi File Connection Manger for this purpose, but this works only when the files have same columns.

**1. My first csv has id, Rate, Amount,Total_Amt  columns

 2. Second Csv File has id, Rate, Amount, Total_Amt, Date, Debt columns

 3. Third CSV File has id, Rate, Amount, Total_Amt, loss, Gain columns**

how can i use multi file connection manager for this approach.

Comment: Sorry, What is the reason to use only one connection Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; the multi file connection manager effectively loops over the files you specify and applies the same settings to each file. If you want different settings you'll either need to use distinct connection managers or create your own connection manager (which would probably only be a wrapper around three individual connection managers anyway).

Sounds like an unusual requirement anyway; what's the reasoning behind only having a single connection manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OLEdb insteat flat file in as [Sathya Narayanan Srinivasan explains in her post](http://geekswithblogs.net/sathya/archive/2010/06/22/how-to-import-and-export-csv-files-directly-in-ssis.aspx).

1. Create a new connection Manager
2. Select New Oledb Connection
3. Select the Provider as Microsoft Jet 4.0 Oledb Provider
4. After choosing that on the same window at the left you will be having two tabs to switch over. one would be All (Which mentions the properties of the connection) and other would be the connection info
5. Choose All. You would see a property called ExtendedProperties.
6. In that paste this without quotes : "text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"
7. There will be another property called Mode, which will mention 16 (readonly) and if you want to  make that Read/Write change it to 19.
8. In the Server or file name text box under the connection tab, give the path of the csv file. Give it only till the folder name and not the csv file itself. (Ex: If your file is c:\sathya\contact.csv give it as c:\sathya)
9. And you can use this Oledb Connection in Oledb Source Task, Lookup task and Oledb Destination task also if you have changed the mode to 19 i.e. read/write.
10. While writing the query to fetch from csv, since you have given only up to the folder as the datasource you need to write query like "select * from contact.csv"

Replace step 10 to make your own querys:

1. select id, Rate, null as Amount, Amount,Total_Amt, null as Date, null as Debt from yourFile.csv
2. select id, Rate, Amount, Total_Amt, Date, Debt  from yourFile.csv
3. so on

Disclaimer: not tested.